# glutMainLoop in mac osx Lion freezes application

Tags: macos, glut

I'm trying to run an example GLUT program, but it only creates a white window and then freezes the application. I found it freezes when calling glutMainLoop (same if I call glutCheckLoop in a loop). Something I may be missing?

Here's the the sample code I found:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

// Question 1: In a GLUT program, how is control passed
// back to the programmer?  How is this set up during
// initialization?

int win_width = 512;
int win_height = 512;

void display( void )
{
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape( int w, int h )
{
  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glLoadIdentity();

  // Question 3: What do the calls to glOrtho()
  // and glViewport() accomplish?
  glOrtho( 0., 1., 0., 1., -1., 1. );
  glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );

  win_width = w;
  win_height = h;

  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y ) {
  switch(key) {
  case 27: // Escape key
    exit(0);
    break;
  }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  // Question 2: What does the parameter to glutInitDisplayMode()
  // specify?
  glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
  glutInitWindowSize( win_width, win_height );

  glutCreateWindow( "Intro Graphics Assignment 1" );

  glutDisplayFunc( display );
  glutReshapeFunc( reshape );
  glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the compiler (works now with gcc)

Comment: lame. glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

int main is not where you want glutMainLoop(), mate.

You should have that in your init method ie initGlutDisplay().

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

// Question 1: In a GLUT program, how is control passed
// back to the programmer?  How is this set up during
// initialization?

int win_width = 512;
int win_height = 512;


void display( void )
{
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape( int w, int h )
{
  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glLoadIdentity();

  // Question 3: What do the calls to glOrtho()
  // and glViewport() accomplish?
  glOrtho( 0., 1., 0., 1., -1., 1. );
  glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );

  win_width = w;
  win_height = h;

  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y ) {
  switch(key) {
  case 27: // Escape key
    exit(0);
    break;
  }
}
int initGlutDisplay(int argc, char* argv[]){
  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  // Question 2: What does the parameter to glutInitDisplayMode()
  // specify?
  glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
  glutInitWindowSize( win_width, win_height );

  glutCreateWindow( "Intro Graphics Assignment 1" );

  glutDisplayFunc( display );
  glutReshapeFunc( reshape );
  glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int win_width = 512;
  int win_height = 512;
  initGlutDisplay(argc, argv);

}
```

The above code should work perfectly.

**EDIT**

According to [opengl](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_on_Mac_OS_X)

> AGL is the old Carbon-based API with C bindings. The Carbon part
>   needed for windowing and event handling are not thread-safe. There is
>   no 64 bit version of this API.

I wonder if this is your issue. I would review the [opengl Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html) by apple to see if you missed any steps that might solve your problem.

Comment: You tried the original code and it failed, then tried your code and it worked? because I'm getting the same freezing result

Comment: yeah my code worked perfect. Interesting, I also tried your code and it worked perfectly. http://s13.postimage.org/rmq3psp7r/Screenshot_1.png